# Building jzmq on OS-X (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, zeromq, jzmq

I'm getting the following error when trying to build jzmq
https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq

Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
./autogen.sh 
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I config --force -I config
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:13: error: 'AM_CONFIG_HEADER': this macro is obsolete.
    You should use the 'AC_CONFIG_HEADERS' macro instead.
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.13.1/share/aclocal-1.13/obsolete-err.m4:14: AM_CONFIG_HEADER is expanded from...
configure.in:13: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
autogen.sh: error: autoreconf exited with status 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename this file:

```
mv configure.in configure.ac
```

Now edit that file and change this line:
old:

```
AM_CONFIG_HEADER(src/config.hpp)
```

new:

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADER(src/config.hpp)
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, I tried the same thing on CentOS 6.5 but I am still facing this. I get " .ibtoolize: AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([config]) conflicts with ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS=-I config autoreconf: libtoolize failed with exit status: 1
autogen.sh: error: autoreconf exited with status 0

"